# iphone count down event

Tags: iphone, count, nsdate

I just want to know how to make a count down for a even or a day? i did some search on google but I got got some few information to make this application ,they told me should be using NSDate and NSCalendar.however I want to stored all information and user can load when reopen  the application ,should I using sqlite or core data? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

```
1. Store your time (NSDate) at the appropriate time.
        NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"CheckedInTime"];
        [defaults synchronize];
```

1. When your app become active again:
   (i.e.) -

   (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Start a timer to check to see if the time has expired:

```
 self.checkinTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(checkinTimerCheck:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) checkinTimerCheck:(NSTimer *) timer {
    NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];            
    NSDate * checkinTime = [defaults objectForKey:@"CheckedInTime"];

    float hours = HOWEVER_MANY_HOURS_NEED_TO_PASS_TO_EXPIRE_IN_SECONDS;
    if (hours < 0) {
        [self alertUserThatTimeHasExpired];
    }
}
```

Invalidate the timer check whenever your app gets

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Regards,

Ken